# How to implement a custom ColumnSorter with ScrollTable (GWT-incubator)

Tags: java, sorting, gwt

I've implemented my custom column sorter which is used to sort the
elements in my table.

```
    class FileColumnSorter extends SortableGrid.ColumnSorter
    {
        @Override
        public void onSortColumn(SortableGrid sortableGrid, TableModelHelper.ColumnSortList columnSortList,
                                SortableGrid.ColumnSorterCallback columnSorterCallback)
        ....
    }
```

When I initialize the FixedWidthGrid I do the following:

```
FixedWidthGrid dataTable = new FixedWidthGrid(rows, cols);
dataTable.setSelectionPolicy(SelectionGrid.SelectionPolicy.ONE_ROW);
dataTable.setColumnSorter(new FileColumnSorter());
```

The scrolltable is initialized the following way:

```
FixedWidthFlexTable headerTable = createHeaderTable();

// Calling the lines described above
FixedWidthGrid fileListGrid = createDataTable
(currentDescriptorList.size(), 6);

// Combine the components into a ScrollTable
scrollTable = new ScrollTable(fileListGrid, headerTable);
scrollTable.setSortPolicy(AbstractScrollTable.SortPolicy.SINGLE_CELL);
scrollTable.setColumnSortable(0, false);
scrollTable.setColumnSortable(1, true);
scrollTable.setColumnSortable(2, true);
scrollTable.setColumnSortable(3, true);
scrollTable.setColumnSortable(4, true);
scrollTable.setColumnSortable(5, false);
```

When I run the application, I get the built in sorting instead of my
custom sorting. I've also tried to do the following:

```
ColumnSorter sorter = new FileColumnSorter();
FixedWidthGrid dataTable = new FixedWidthGrid(rows, cols) {
    @Override
    public ColumnSorter getColumnSorter()
    {
        return sorter;
    }
};
```

To ensure that my sorter get used, but I still get the same
experience.

**Update: Added the FileColumnSorter**

```
class FileColumnSorter extends SortableGrid.ColumnSorter
{
    @Override
    public void onSortColumn(SortableGrid sortableGrid,
        TableModelHelper.ColumnSortList columnSortList,
        SortableGrid.ColumnSorterCallback columnSorterCallback)
    {
        final int column = columnSortList.getPrimaryColumn();

        final Integer[] originalOrder = new Integer[sortableGrid.getRowCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < originalOrder.length; i++)
        {
            originalOrder[i] = i;
        }

        Arrays.sort(originalOrder, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            public int compare(Integer first, Integer second)
            {
                Descriptor firstDesc = share.getCurrentDescriptors().get(first);
                Descriptor secondDesc = share.getCurrentDescriptors().get(second);

                if (firstDesc.getType().equals(secondDesc.getType()))
                {
                    switch (column)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            return firstDesc.compareTo(secondDesc);
                        case 1:
                            return firstDesc.getName().compareTo(secondDesc.getName());
                        case 2:
                            return ((Long) firstDesc.getSize()).compareTo(secondDesc.getSize());
                        case 3:
                            return firstDesc.getCreated().compareTo(secondDesc.getCreated());
                        case 4:
                            return firstDesc.getModified().compareTo(secondDesc.getModified());
                        default:
                            return firstDesc.compareTo(secondDesc);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return firstDesc.getType() == Descriptor.FileItemType.FOLDER ? 1 : -1;
                }
            }
        });

        int[] resultOrder = new int[originalOrder.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < originalOrder.length; i++)
        {
            if (columnSortList.isPrimaryAscending())
            {
                resultOrder[i] = originalOrder[i];
            }
            else
            {
                resultOrder[resultOrder.length - i - 1] = originalOrder[i];
            }
        }
        columnSorterCallback.onSortingComplete(resultOrder);
    }
}
```

Comment: This pattern works for me. Can you add the code for `FileColumnSorter` ?

Comment: Have updated the with the sorter implementation. This includes a descriptor which is a DTO with some basic fields.

Comment: Silly question -- you have FileColumnSort as the class name in the posted code, but instantiate FileColumnSorter.  Just in case you've actually got two different classes going by accident and instantiated the wrong one...

Comment: No - it's just me writing it wrong in here.

Answer (score 1):

I found this great example on how to use a PagingScrollTable with GWT incubator. Maybe you can use this instead of implementing your own: http://zenoconsulting.wikidot.com/blog:17